# Creating an image to use in Windows 7 XP mode?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have an XP laptop that I want to create an image of and use
in Windows 7 XP mode.

Is this a good idea or what??
And how do I do it please?

The laptop's drive is about 60GB full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the XP to a virtual disk using [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) and use it with Microsoft Virtual PC (but I can't guarantee that you wouldn't need to reactivate its license).

You can use the technique described in this article :
[Make Your Own VHD to XP Mode or even Vista Mode Ready](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/09/how-to-make-your-own-vhd-to-xp-mode-or-even-vista-mode-ready/):

> However, in
>   lot of cases, you may want to just use
>   your already working XP VHD image for
>   XP mode in Windows 7. The good news is
>   it’s totally possible, and the better
>   news is it’s dead simple.
>
> The key to make it work in XP mode is
>   to enable the new setting called Auto
>   Publish in the latest version Virtual
>   PC.

Therefore, as described in this article, you **CAN** replace the Microsoft's XP Mode VHD by your own generated by Disk2vhd.